# Advantaged and disadvantages of using switch statements without curly braces

Tags: php, performance, syntax, switch-statement, conditional-statements

```
switch($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]){
    case "/index.php":
            $this->pageId = 1;
        break;
    case "/shops/index.php":
            $this->pageId = 2;
        break;
    case "/shops/dailydeals.php":
            $this->pageId = 4;
        break;
    case "/shops/shops.php":
            $this->pageId = 5;
        break;
    case "/shops/deals.php":
            $this->pageId = 9;
        break;
    case "/shops/store.php":
            $this->pageId = 10;
        break;
    case "/user/cashmail.php":
            $this->pageId = 13;
        break;
    case "/user/cashmail.php":
            $this->pageId = 13;
        break;
    default ;
            $this->pageId = 1;
        break;
    }
```

What do you say about the above code?  I am trying to decide if I should use curly braces on my `case` arms or not. Each case in my example only has one line of code, so I am not using curly braces.  Is there a performance difference between using with or without curly braces?

Answer (score 8):

I am going to add my own answer to this question because the accepted answer isn't correct.

"Multiline" case clauses **can** be written with curly braces. Whether or not one should is completely up to the developer that is writing the code and/or up to the coding standards that they subscribe to.

I personally use curly braces in case statements in every programming language I utilize, starting with C, because I believe it creates for more readable code.

And no, it's not a syntax error.

In regards to performance. Well, PHP is interpreted, so technically it has to interpret the curly braces. However, you should not sacrifice readability for such a negligible performance gain. Especially in a language like PHP, where performance implications go far beyond the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I find this question to be similar to: "Should I wash my car with a dirty sponge or a greasy sponge?"  The answer is of course, "neither".

I see no compelling reason to bloat your file with the verbosity of a `switch()` block.  Because you are merely translating one value into another value, you only need a "mapping" or "lookup" array to leverage.

This will help you catch silly coding mistakes like duplicating a case in your switch block (for example):

```
case "/user/cashmail.php":
        $this->pageId = 13;
    break;
```

The advantage of a lookup is concise code that is easier to scan (with human eyes) and maintain.  It is also very fast because php does a terrific job of hunting for key values in an array.  I should also state that because your lookup array values can reasonably be assumed static, you can safely declare them as constants.  Once this code structure is in place, you only ever need to maintain the lookup array and never the processing line of code.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rse8b))

```
define(
    'PATH_TO_PAGE_ID_LOOKUP',
    [
        "/index.php" => 1,
        "/shops/index.php" => 2,
        "/shops/dailydeals.php" => 4,
        "/shops/shops.php" => 5,
        "/shops/deals.php" => 9,
        "/shops/store.php" => 10,
        "/user/cashmail.php" => 13,
    ]
);
define('DEFAULT_PAGE_ID', 1);

$this->pageId = PATH_TO_PAGE_ID_LOOKUP[$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]] ?? DEFAULT_PAGE_ID;
echo $this->pageId;  // 9
```

---

That said, from PHP8 and higher, you can also enjoy the brevity of [a `match()` block](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) which is the beautiful child of a switch and a lookup array.

A `match()` control structure can look like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vY4hr))

```
$this->pageId = match ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) {
    "/index.php" => 1,
    "/shops/index.php" => 2,
    "/shops/dailydeals.php" => 4,
    "/shops/shops.php" => 5,
    "/shops/deals.php" => 9,
    "/shops/store.php" => 10,
    "/user/cashmail.php" => 13,
    default => 1,
};

echo $this->pageId; // 9
```

This is probably the cleanest way to perform this task in modern php.  Perhaps the only reasons you wouldn't use this technique are: if you are not yet using PHP8, or maybe if you plan to use the lookup array in multiple places/ways AND having a single point of reference offers some additional benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** use curly braces so that case subroutines can be [folded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding) for readability.